# htaccess question

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm having the following modrewrite structure:

```
/links/
/links/web/
/links/travel/
..
```

the corresponding .htaccess would be:

```
RewriteRule ^links/ links.php [L]
RewriteRule ^links/web/ links.php?catID=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^links/travel/ links.php?catID=2 [L]
```

the problem is that the root link (first line) will always trigger before the actual category-links.
is there a way to fix this? the only way i found was modifying the root link to:

```
^links/index.html
```

but i'd like to omit the index.html - any ideas how this is possible?

Comment: Why not place the first RewriteRule after the other RewriteRules?

Comment: good idea .. but i'm building this out of a database some seo dude is editing - so he'd always add the root rule first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `$`:

```
RewriteRule ^links/$ links.php [L]
```

It signifies the end of the URL.

Alternatively you can do the check inside PHP, if you evaluate `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

Answer (score 1):

just reverse it. If no /web/ check for /links/ again

```
RewriteRule ^links/travel/ links.php?catID=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^links/web/ links.php?catID=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^links/ links.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the first line last; that way, it will be executed after the others.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following RewriteRule first might do it (I haven't tested):

```
RewriteRule ^links/$ links/index.html [L]
```